Unable to use images from local docker inside k8s node ( pre pull image )
We have built k8s using kubeadm and setup 3 nodes machines (which we have root access to)
We want to use the feature of k8s that they call according to their docs "pre-pull images" which is that pods that will be created on nodes - will use the local docker images vs the public internet.
Problem is it's not working.
Running the below command on all nodes - will have the same result
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
busybox                              latest    65ad0d468eb1   12 months ago    4.26MB
mybusybox                            latest    65ad0d468eb1   12 months ago    4.26MB

I tagged the busybox -> mybusybox just to make sure that the pod isn't taking the busybox image from Docker Hub.
So i'm trying to run k8s with the following:
kubectl run hello-world-0 -ti --image=mybusybox --image-pull-policy=Never --restart=Never

When running kubectl describe hello-world-0 I see that it got assigned to a node that i'm 100% sure the image exists on ( per output above )
But I'm receiving the following error
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------             ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled          2m33s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ns-test/hello-world-0 to ip-172-x-x-x.europe.compute.internal
  Warning  Failed             32s (x12 over 2m32s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImageNeverPull
  Warning  ErrImageNeverPull  19s (x13 over 2m32s)  kubelet            Container image "mybusybox" is not present with pull policy of Never


I will just note, that also from the node itself when I try running:
node1$ sudo docker pull mybusybox
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for mybusybox, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

but I'm not really sure if this error is related to the error that k8s receive in the pods ?
We never configured any credentials, we just installed Docker so I'm not sure that the login is the issue ...
Appreciate any help here ...

Why people are voting to close this question w/o any comment ?

Kubelet will try to pull the image from public docker repo if the repository name is not specified. More details of this is mentioned in k8s documentation.
Please push the images to private repo which needs to used. Pull the images into nodes manually.  Post that image pull policy "Never" can be used.
Below is sample
kubectl run hello-world-0 --image=private-repo-name/mybusybox --image-pull-policy=Never --restart=Never

But the images are already in the nodes ... when running docker images i see them - the command above - is one of the nodes machine

Please do docker login to dockerhub in worker nodes.  Post that pod will be able to use images which are already in nodes.

and what would you write in the --image= parameter ? At the moment it gives me: failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/mybusybox:latest"

Kindly use "--image=busybox" which maps to dockerhub image name.  As the image is already there in node it will not download again.  Latest error is because as "mybusybox" would havent been there in your repo.

so that brings me back to my original question, i've build my image locally on the node itself, it's inside docker, yet, i'm unable to pull it ( not via docker and not via kubectl run .. because it saying - it doesn't exists. so what I need to do in order for k8s to "pre-pull" them ?

kubelet will try pull images from dockerhub if repo is not mentioned in "--image=" attribute.  you can use private repo and push images

yeah ... i know about the registry that docker has ... but wanted the pre-pulled images on the nodes. but I gave up on that, it doesn't seems to work, and the only option probably, is to create a pod with a registry image + ssl and just use it ... thanks for the advice !

The issue was a DNS issue, specifically on CentOS 7+
K8S has its own internal DNS service that creates domains automatically so that pods can talk to services etc w/o specifying a static IP ( which might change when you stop/start services )
I'm talking about the domains that are constructed by:
<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<service-port>

That service (created by coredns or kube-dns)

created domains in network: 192.x.x.x
But pods were created in network: 10.x.x.x

Github bug was reported here:
Fresh deploy with CoreDNS not resolving any dns lookup
#1056
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1056
What solved it, was to upgrade the cluster component to a specific version. meaning, delete the entire cluster, upgrade/reinstall and recreate it.

This issue happened because the image was not pushed to the repository.
Make sure your image is tagged as mybusybox:latest and imagePullPolicy is set to Always.
Execute this command: docker push mybusybox:latest
Hopefully, this will help you.

This question is asking how not to use Docker Hub; the expectation is that images aren't pushed to a registry.
